# request rest api and return response values for a mocha test

Tags: node.js, rest, mocha.js, supertest

Inside a meteor appliation, i want to test some rest functions, therefore i need to do some authentication.

In my testcase, i want to return some auth data from a function:

```
const supertest = require('supertest');

function loginUser(auth) {
  return function(done) {
    request
      .post('/users/login')
      .send({
        username: 'user'
        password: '123',
      })
      .expect(200)
      .end(onResponse);

    function onResponse(err, res) {
      auth.token = res.body.token;
      return done();
    }
  };
}
```

inside this test:

```
it('auth test by helper function', function () {
  let auth = {};
  auth = loginUser(auth)(done);
  //access auth settings here like:
  //auth.token
});
```

`onResponse` is never called and `auth` is always `{}`

I am using supertest for requests 3.0.0 and mocha 4.1.0 as testrunner (The rest api is simple:json-routes)

**UPDATE**

It seems like the return 'function(done)' is never called...

Ok i fixed the call to `auth = loginUser(auth)(done);`

Now the call is done but `auth` is undefined after the call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `function loginUser(auth)` returns another function. So you should call that function as well like this:

```
it('auth test by helper function', function (done) { // pass done so mocha knows it needs to wait for the response ...
  let auth = {};
  loginUser(auth)(function() {
     //access auth settings here like:
     //auth.token
     done();
  });       
});
```

Comment: i have changed my code to call the function like in your answer. Call is executed but i think mocha is not waiting. `auth` is `{}` when i want to acces the token.